# div won't stretch to bottom of screen

Tags: css

Ive created a webpage as you can see below, however i can't make the a section of the page to stretch all the way to the bottom as you can see by the dark area in the image. I've done research and searched through som of the similar posts in here but nothing i've tried seem to do the trick.

Height:100%; position:relative; Doesnt work

Height:auto; min-height:100%; Doesnt work

Bottom:0; Doesnt work

[image]

```css
html{
    height:100%;
}

#home {
    background: url(../img/chemical.jpg) no-repeat center center; /*Full Witdth background image*/
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    min-height: 600px;
    width:auto;
    min-width:100%;
}
    /*STYLE FOR OVERLAY CLASS - WHICH IS ABOVE IMAGE WITH OPACITY/TRANSPARENCY 0.75*/
    #home .overlay {
        padding-bottom:20%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 116, 112,0.6); /*.75 opacity of the color so that background image is visible*/
        min-height: 600px;
        color: #fff;
        width:auto;
        min-width:100%;
}

body {
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: #222;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
}

#page-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="wrapper" style="height:auto; min-height:100%">

   <!-- Navigation -->
   <?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>

   <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div id="home">
        <div class="overlay">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">
                        View All Overdue Lab Tests
                    </h1>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="active">
                            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->

            <div class="row" style="height:100%">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right fa-fw"></i> All Overdue Lab Test:
                            <button style="float:right; height:25px; width:200px; color:black; border-radius:25px 25px 25px 25px;" value="hello">Prompt Overdue Items</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" style="color:black;">
                            "Table Data"
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

     </div>
     <!-- /.container-fluid -->
   </div>
   </div>    
   </div>
   <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Which div you want to take 100%? Class or ID name?

Comment: You should use 100% on the `<body>` and  `<html>`...then all the parent elements should use 100% where your child element will use 100%. I hope that was clear.

Comment: @XahedKamal both #home and .overlay

Comment: Can you create JSFiddle with complete HTML and CSS? What you have in your codes, doesn't match with image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

100% height elements will only be 100% of the viewport if all parents have 100% height.

To start:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

As well as the two parents `#wrapper` and `#page-wrapper`.

The alternative is to use 'Viewport Units' like `vh`.

```
#home {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

That will work regardless of parents heights. Here is the [caniuse browser support table.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)